# Error on Adreno200-ES20 with GLSurfaceView on Nexus 4 with Android 4.3

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

The code I am using works fine on Nexus 7 (2013), but as soon as I try to run it on a Nexus 4 (intentional left with Android 4.3), I get this error messages, which fills up the Logcat.

```
03-11 15:02:01.414: E/Adreno200-GSL(3695): <gsl_command_waittimestamp:1868>: Cannot wait for invalid ts <24:0xa>, last queued ts <24:0x1>
03-11 15:02:01.414: E/Adreno200-ES20(3695): <rb_timestamp_wait_on_timestamp:353>: gsl_device_waittimestamp failed in rb_timestamp_wait_on_timestamp
03-11 15:02:01.444: E/Adreno200-GSL(3695): <gsl_command_waittimestamp:1868>: Cannot wait for invalid ts <24:0xc>, last queued ts <24:0x1>
03-11 15:02:01.444: E/Adreno200-ES20(3695): <rb_timestamp_wait_on_timestamp:353>: gsl_device_waittimestamp failed in rb_timestamp_wait_on_timestamp
03-11 15:02:01.484: E/Adreno200-GSL(3695): <gsl_command_waittimestamp:1868>: Cannot wait for invalid ts <24:0xe>, last queued ts <24:0x1>
03-11 15:02:01.484: E/Adreno200-ES20(3695): <rb_timestamp_wait_on_timestamp:353>: gsl_device_waittimestamp failed in rb_timestamp_wait_on_timestamp
03-11 15:02:01.524: E/Adreno200-GSL(3695): <gsl_command_waittimestamp:1868>: Cannot wait for invalid ts <24:0x10>, last queued ts <24:0x1>
03-11 15:02:01.524: E/Adreno200-ES20(3695): <rb_timestamp_wait_on_timestamp:353>: gsl_device_waittimestamp failed in rb_timestamp_wait_on_timestamp
```

Anyone knows what that could be?
This only occurs, when I use the GLSurfaceView for rendering. If I use the TextureView, it seems to work. But because the textureview is way slower than the GLSurfaceView, I'ld like to stay with it.

Comment: Can you identify actions that trigger this?  e.g. are there things that you can temporarily remove from your code that stop the problem from happening?

Comment: Yep you definitely have to narrow down the part of code causing this and provide this code here. Personally, I haven't encountered this error.

Comment: I'll try to do that...